# Extending from another object without using Object.assign (ES6 feature) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

**Update 1:** I didn't mention this earlier, but I was trying to avoid using the *new* keyword. The [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) should work just fine, as well. I should have been clear that I was looking to see if there was an alternative way of writing similar code.

---

Chris Elliott's article ['Common Misconceptions about Inheritance in JS'](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/common-misconceptions-about-inheritance-in-javascript-d5d9bab29b0a) illustrates a great way to use closures for data privacy, but does so with the ES6 method *[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)*.

He describes it as:

> `Object.assign()` is a new ES6 feature championed by Rick Waldron that was previously implemented in a few dozen libraries. You might know it as `$.extend()` from jQuery or `_.extend()` from Underscore. Lodash has a version of it called `assign()`. You pass in a destination object, and as many source objects as you like, separated by commas.
>
> It will copy all of the enumerable own properties by assignment from
>   the source objects to the destination objects with last in priority.
>   If there are any property name conflicts, the version from the last
>   object passed in wins.

How can I write this sample **without** using the ES6 feature *Object.assign*?

```
let animal = {
  animalType: 'animal',

  describe () {
    return `An ${this.animalType} with ${this.furColor} fur, 
      ${this.legs} legs, and a ${this.tail} tail.`;
  }
};

let mouseFactory = function mouseFactory () {
  let secret = 'secret agent';

  return Object.assign(Object.create(animal), {
    animalType: 'mouse',
    furColor: 'brown',
    legs: 4,
    tail: 'long, skinny',
    profession () {
      return secret;
    }
  });
};

let james = mouseFactory();
```

Comment: Use lodash or underscore, or loop over the elements and copy the properties.

Comment: Or use the polyfill on the MDN `Object.assign` page.

Comment: That's likely what I'll end up doing.

Comment: Just a note, but the "update" style tends to make your question harder to read for people not following it from the beginning. Or at least put them at the end.

Comment: All objects are garbage collected, whether they are created using `new` or in any other way.

Comment: I thought that using Object.create would not return a new function each time it was called though, and that was the benefit of using it. Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just use `Object.create` which is ES5 as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

I have rewritten your code in this format, there you go:

```
var animal = {
  animalType: 'animal',

  describe: function() {
    return 'An ' + this.animalType + ' with ' + this.furColor + ' fur, ' 
      + this.legs + ' legs, and a ' + this.tail + ' tail.';
  }
};

var mouseFactory = function mouseFactory () {
  var secret = 'secret agent';

  return Object.create(animal, {
    animalType: {
        value: 'mouse',
        writable: true
    },
    furColor: {
        value: 'brown',
        writable: true
    },
    legs: {
        value: 4,
        writable: true        
    },
    tail: {
        value: 'long, skinny',
        writable: true        
    },
    profession: {
        value: function () {
          return secret;
        }
    }
  });
};

var james = mouseFactory();

var dave = mouseFactory();
dave.furColor = 'white';

console.log(james.describe());
// An mouse with brown fur, 4 legs, and a long, skinny tail.

console.log(dave.describe());
// An mouse with white fur, 4 legs, and a long, skinny tail.
```

Comment: This is how I considered using it as well. Will that point to the same instance each time I create a new variable behind it?

For example, these two variables refer to two different instances of the object?

var james = mouseFactory(); // returns first instance
var dave = mouseFactory(); // returns a second instance

Comment: Correct. I have just edited my example adding 'writable: true' to the arguments. Now I have created a 2nd variable, ```dave```, changed its fur color to white and when I call describe on both I still have different results. Which proves they are 2 different instances

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By writing your own version of object.assign!

```
function assign(target, sources) {
    // for each object in source, iterate through properties
    // check has own property and add the property to the target 
    // object

    // or just modify in place, too many different ways to do this
    let newTarget = new target();


    for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
      for (let key in sources[i]) {
        if (sources[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          newTarget[key] = sources[i][key];
        }
      }
    }
    return newTarget;
}
```

EDIT: You absolutely don't have to use new - you could also just add them to an empty object.

```
function assign(sources) {
    // for each object in source, iterate through properties
    // check has own property and add the property to the target 
    // object

    // this is not the important part
    let newTarget = {};


    for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
      for (let key in sources[i]) {
        if (sources[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          newTarget[key] = sources[i][key];
        }
      }
    }
    return newTarget;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I could do it this way as well. Thanks for the clarification!